# Stop Visual Studio 2015 C# from changing #region column position

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am busy adding some #if/#endif around blocks of C# code and each time I start typing the "#" Visual Studio will pull back (to 1st column) all my #region/#endregion lines that follow below.

It does not do this in VS2013. Is there a setting to prevent this?